# MySQL returning Object of RowDataPacket to node js express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, express

I am trying to select items from the DB but every time i call the select statment SQL returns an RowDataPacket object and i cant seem to find a way to access that object. What i am trying to do is to call that object from ejs file.

**this is my ejs file**

```
<%- include('../partials/header', {title:title}) %> 
<body>
    <%- include("../partials/nav", {title: title}) %>

    <div class="contaienr">
        <p><% console.log(Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)))[0]) %> </p>
        <img src="<%= res.bild %> ">
        <h2><%= res.namn %> </h2>
        <p><%= res.beskrivning %> </p>
        <form action="">
            <button></button>
            <input type="number" name="" id="" min="1" max="<%= res.antal %> ">
        </form>
    </div>  
    <%- include("../partials/footer", {title: title}) %>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the function that gets the data**

```
async function getProduct(id)
{
    let sql = `CALL get_product(?)`;
    let res;

    res = await db.query(sql, [id]);

    console.log(res);

    return res;
}
```

**and this is the function that displays the page**

```
router.get("/product/:id", async (req, res) =>
{
    let id = req.params.id;
    let data = {
        title : `Product ${id} | BuckStar`,
        product : id
    }

    data.res = results.getProduct(id);

    res.render("pages/product", data);  
});
```

**this is the output in the console**

```
    undefined
[
[
    RowDataPacket {
    kod: 1111,
    kategori: 'Arabica',
    namn: 'Coffe 1',
    beskrivning: 'I am a coffe',
    pris: 100,
    antal: 0,
    plats: '1A',
    bild: '1'
    }
],
OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0
}
]
```